# How to open a page then run a script only if page opened from other page

Tags: javascript

How do I run a script on a page only if the page was opened from another page?

I have this page element:

```
    <div id="Devotion_alert"></div>
```

I add a span with onclick to that div.

```
    var show_devotion_alert = '<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="open_livemass();"><br/>'+devotion_name+' '+time_info+'<br/>('+devotion_channel.name+')</span>';
    $('#Devotion_alert').html(show_devotion_alert);
```

When the user clicks on the element I want to run a script:

```
function open_livemass() {
    window.location.href = 'livemass_RECORDED.php';
    // want to select elements on the new page and load element content
}
```

When the new page loads I want to select page elements and load element content.  I only want to do that if the new page was opened with a mouseclick from the previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Found that the most practical solution was to send variables in the URL to tell the new page what to do.  If the variables are not there, the page will be the same as if it were opened directly.  If the variables are there, a javascript function will load the page elements.

From the referrer page onclick I open the new page with this:

```
    window.location.href = 'livemass_RECORDED.php?show_next='+show_next+'&idx='+idx;
```

In the livemass_RECORDED.php page I read the variables and fill the necessary elements.

```
<?php 
    $show_next = $_REQUEST['show_next'];
    $channel_idx = $_REQUEST['idx'];
?>
    <script>
        var show_next = "<?php echo $show_next; ?>";
        var channel_idx = <?php echo $channel_idx; ?>;
        alert (' LIVEMASS show next '+show_next+' channel '+channel_idx);
        if ( show_next.search(/Devotion/i) != -1 ) {
        }
        else if ( show_next.search(/Mass/i) != -1 ) {
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to have a form submitted with a hidden field. Then if the receiving page sees that the hidden field value is set, it can load the element content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this in javascript you can try checking `document.referrer`, but be aware that it won't always be present.

Comment: document.referrer sounds like a good option.  But I have two different links on the referring page and want to load different page elements based on the link clicked.  What if I send a php variable `livemass.php?show_next=Mass`, and then read that variable to determine what needs to be done? `<?php 
    $show_next = $_REQUEST['show_next'];
?>
<script>
 alert('show next '+<?php $show_next ?>);
</script>`

Comment: Oh I see, if you can use PHP then yes that's an easier and more reliable way to go. Do you already have the page elements on the page and hidden?

Comment: The page elements are on the page.  They are not hidden, I only need to set their .html.

Comment: For a really clean solution look into returning JSON from the php script, and if you can use jQuery the `$.getJSON()` method makes getting that data via AJAX very easy.

Comment: I haven't done this before.  How would I change the php code shown in the comments to use JSON/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how reliable you want your code to work.  You could add a cookie `open_livemass` then check for its existence/value on the page.  You would expire the cookie when no longer needed

Comment: If I open the url with `livemass.php?show_next=Mass`, will this work better than a cookie? `<?php 
    $show_next = $_REQUEST['show_next'];
?>
<script>
 alert('show next '+<?php $show_next ?>);
</script>`

Comment: 'Better' is relative, but yes it will work.  Using a url parameter is simple and you can access the parameter both on the server and with pure javascript (via `location.search`).  Of course the url is the easiest for the user to modify.  It all depends on your requirements